# C - value changed in function doesn't change in main() despite using pointers

Tags: c

The function row_stats is supposed to update the value stored by variable max_ptr with maximum number from a given row of the array. I tried looking it up in other questions here but it didn't help. Could someone please explain me where is the mistake?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void row_stats(int(*ptr)[5], int width, int row_id, int* max) {
    int i = 0;
    int curr = ptr[row_id][0];

    while (i < width) {
        if (ptr[row_id][i] > curr) {
            curr = ptr[row_id][i];
        }

        i++;
    }
    max = &curr;
    printf("max: %d\n", *max);
}

int main() {
    int a[5][5] = {
        {1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
        {6, 7, 8, 9, 10},
        {11, 12, 13, 14, 15},
        {16, 17, 18, 19, 20},
        {21, 22, 23, 24, 25}
    };

    int* max_ptr;
    row_stats(a, 5, 3, max_ptr);
    printf("after funct: %d", *max_ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "value changed in function doesn't change in main()", where did you previously store the value in main()?.

Comment: @Murali, in line:
 int* max_ptr;

Answer (score 1):

```
max = &curr;
```

semantically makes no sense. `max` is a *local copy* of the `max_ptr` from main, you are changing the copy to point to a local variable.  Both the pointer copy and the local variable are discarded on return.

You need to modify what *max* *points to* thus:

```
*max = curr ;
```

However in this case it points to nothing defined.  In main you need also need to change:

```
int* max_ptr;
row_stats(a, 5, 3, max_ptr);
```

to

```
int max ;
row_stats(a, 5, 3, &max ) ;
```

`&max` is a pointer to `max`.

All that said, in this case the use of a reference parameter is ill advised if you only wish to return an `int` and are not already using the return value for something else. The safer and simpler method would be to simply return the value:

```
int row_stats( int(*ptr)[5], int width, int row_id ) 
{
    ...    
    return curr ;
}
```

then

```
int max = row_stats( a, 5, 3 ) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

In the function, `max` can be set to point to an array index. To do that, `int **max` is needed and pass the address of the pointer to the function.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void row_stats(int(*ptr)[5], int width, int row_id, int** max) {
    int i = 0;
    *max = &ptr[row_id][0]; // points to an array element
    while (i < width) {
        if (ptr[row_id][i] > **max) {
            *max = &ptr[row_id][i]; // points to an array element
        }
        i++;
    }
    printf("max: %d\n", **max);
}
int main(void) {
    int a[5][5]={{1,2,3,4,5},{6,7,8,9,10},{11,12,13,14,15},{16,17,18,19,20},{21,22,23,24,25}};
    int* max_ptr;
    row_stats(a,5,3,&max_ptr); // pass address of pointer
    printf("after funct: %d\n", *max_ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    max = &curr;
```

Sets max to point to a variable inside the function. Did you mean

```
    *max = curr;
```

```
    int* max_ptr;
    row_stats(a, 5, 3, max_ptr);
```

But it was never initialized so it ponts into somewhere arbitrary. Anything can happen.

It's like you meant:

```
    int max;
    int* max_ptr = &max;
    row_stats(a, 5, 3, max_ptr);
```

There's ways to simplify the code but it looks like an exercise so I'm going with this.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things, you must change.

First, you should pass an address to an int, not a pointer, e.g.

```
int max;
row_stats(a, 5, 3, &max);
printf("after funct: %d", max);
```

and then you must return the maximum value.
Not by assigning the address of a local variable to the local pointer parameter, but by assigning the maximum value to the integer stored outside of `row_stats`:

```
*max = curr;
```